# One huge drive (network share) from many computers, with folder priority redundancy

Tags: storage, storage-area-network

Not sure if this exists, but I have a huge amount of data to store (about 5-50mb files) and as it is now, I have 5 computers, each with raid 5 providing about 6TB hard drive each. This is causing some problems with the software I am using (something home made) so I'm wondering, is there some software that I can install on all those computers that will mask it as one huge drive...
Running windows on those computers, from Xp 64 bit to windows server 2008

I would also like to set a priority on each folder on the redundancy it has, some folders I can live without no online backup (I have a backup in a safe of that data) but some I need full online backup system if one hard drive fails.

Something open source, as I try to use that as much as I can, but all ideas welcome.

Comment: dfs is the way to go if you can use sub dirs under the root share, if not then maybe a software based iscsi solution might work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came across something called GlusterFS which seems to be what I'm looking for.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GlusterFS

Answer (score 2):

With Windows, you have the option of DFS is you're using the Server versions in an AD domain. It won't interleave the folder structure (no one big folder), but you can certainly set up something like:

```
\\server\share\dir1
\\server\share\dir2
\\server\share\dir3
```

Where the dir[1|2|3] are actually hosted on some other server. Samba doesn't yet recognize DFS shares, so that may be a problem on the client side.

Something similar can be done with Samba as a server, though I'm not 100% sure how to set it up.

```
ln -s 'msdfs:server1\share' dir1
```

Should create a symlink that DFS-aware clients (which, oddly, Sabma isn't) should understand and follow.

Comment: That sort of sums it up. Replciation can be enabled, too. If you need a flat space, GlusterFS etc. work, but are not available on windows to my knowledge.

Comment: creating a common name space for files and folders is exactly one of the things DFS was designed for.

Answer (score 0):

I recently came across MPFS (Multy Path File System) that does something like this, but I don't think it is free.

Comment: I came across something called GlusterFS which seems to be what I'm looking for.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GlusterFS

Answer (score 0):

What you want is called a "Distributed File-system", see [the Wikipedia list of distributed file-systems](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_file_systems#Distributed_file_systems).  The section you want is probably the "Distributed, parallel, fault-tolerant file-systems" section.  I'm not really familiar with Windows, so I can't make any recommendations, but if you were under Linux I'd recommend GlusterFS.  It does what you want, except for allowing per-folder redundancy settings, you'd need to set up different file-systems with different redundancy settings I believe.